# How can I use a hashmap or map of an array to return the category with the highest total?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

Here is my array.

```
donations = [
 {
      donateTo: "BaseCamp",
      amount: 1000,
      date: "12/19/2014, 08:40"
 },
 {
      donateTo: "Where Most Needed",
      amount: 3000,
      date: "12/12/2014, 08:40"
 },
 {
      donateTo: "Where Most Needed",
      amount: 2000,
      date: "12/11/2014, 08:40"
 }
 ];
```

How can I return something like this? Where the donation with the `donateTo` that has the highest total donations is returned along with that total and the count of the gifts that made up that total.

```
{ donateTo: "Where Most Needed", total: 5000, count: 2}
```

I was previously able to get the results with MongoDB, but because I'm using Meteor, the aggregation is really ugly and not reactive. I'd rather fetch the cursor and then use a javascript function on the client side to get the data I need out.

Thanks

Comment: you can't. have to use a loop and do it by hand. i recommend returning some sort of id for your `donateTo` property so you don't have to compare repeatedly on strings.

Comment: Related question, may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation using underscore:

```
var orgs = {};

_.each(donations, function(donation) {
  if (orgs[donation.donateTo] == null)
    orgs[donation.donateTo] = 0;
  orgs[donation.donateTo] += donation.amount;
});

var amount = _.max(_.values(orgs));
var donateTo = _.invert(orgs)[amount];
var count = _.where(donations, {donateTo: donateTo}).length;
var result = {donateTo: donateTo, amount: amount, count: count};
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the items and group them in an object, then loop through the properties in the object to find the largest amount:

```js
var donations = [
  {
      donateTo: "BaseCamp",
      amount: 1000,
      date: "12/19/2014, 08:40"
  },
  {
      donateTo: "Where Most Needed",
      amount: 3000,
      date: "12/12/2014, 08:40"
  },
  {
      donateTo: "Where Most Needed",
      amount: 2000,
      date: "12/11/2014, 08:40"
  }
];

var sums = {};
for (var i = 0; i < donations.length; i++) {
  var donateTo = donations[i].donateTo;
  if (sums.hasOwnProperty(donateTo)) {
    sums[donateTo].amount += donations[i].amount;
    sums[donateTo].count++;
  } else {
    sums[donateTo] = { donateTo: donateTo, amount: donations[i].amount, count: 1 };
  }
}

var obj = null;
for (donateTo in sums) {
  if (obj == null || sums[donateTo].amount > obj.amount) {
    obj = sums[donateTo];
  }
}

// show in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first iterate the documents to group them together by the `donateTo` field.

```
var m = {}; // to hold the grouped records by `donateTo`
 donations.forEach(function(i){
    if(!m[i["donateTo"]]){
        m[i["donateTo"]] = {};
        m[i["donateTo"]] = i;
        m[i["donateTo"]]["count"] = 1;
    }
    else{
        m[i["donateTo"]]["count"]++;
        m[i["donateTo"]]["amount"] += i.amount;
    }
 });
```

And then find the group with the greatest amount:

```
 var result = {amount:0}; // to hold the group with the largest amount
 Object.keys(m).forEach(function(key){
    if(m[key].amount > result.amount){
        result = m[key];
    }
 })
delete result["date"];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no super slick way to do this since you have to accumulate all the totals and then pick the highest one at the end and the very last entry in the array could completely change the highest value so you have to accumulate all the sub-totals as you go.

This function below accumulates a map of all the `donateTo` strings encountered and keeps a running total and cnt for each one.  As it goes along, it then keeps track of which `donateTo` key has the highest total so far, saving an extra pass to compute the highest one.

```
function findHighestSum(list) {
    // collect cumulative totals
    var totals = {}, highestTotal = 0, highestKey;
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        var key = item.donateTo;
        if (!totals[key]) {
            totals[key] = {amount: item.amount, cnt: 1};
        } else {
            totals[key].amount += item.amount;
            totals[key].cnt++;
        }
        if (totals[key].amount > highestTotal) {
            highestTotal = totals[key].amount;
            highestKey = key;
        }
    });


    // { donateTo: "Where Most Needed", total: 5000, count: 2}
    return {donateTo: highestKey, total: highestTotal, count: totals[highestKey].cnt};
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7cfdsftz/

Answer (score 0):

Because underscore is fun!

```
_.chain(donations)
  .reduce(function(m, c) {
      var findItem = _.findWhere(m, { 'donateTo': c.donateTo});
      if (findItem) {
          findItem.count++; 
          findItem.total += c.amount;
      } else {
          m.push({
             'donateTo':c.donateTo, 
             'count':1, 
             'total':c.amount});
      };
      return m; }, [])
  .max(function(k) { return k.total})
  .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore...

```
// reduce donations, finally returning object with largest amount total
var highest = _.reduce(donations, function(memo, item, index){
    // add to amount total if group exists, else init group
    if(memo[item.donateTo]){
        memo[item.donateTo].amount += item.amount;
        memo[item.donateTo].count++;
    } else {
        memo[item.donateTo] = {
            donateTo: item.donateTo,
            amount:item.amount,
            count:1
        };
    }
    // if it is last iteration...
    if(index === donations.length - 1){
        // extract the max value
        memo = _.max(_.toArray(memo), function(item){
            return item.amount;
        });
    }
    return memo;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore js ...

```
// return the max (amount) of sorted, and collapsed array
var result = _.max( _.reduce( _.sortBy(donations, 'donateTo'), function(memo, item){
    // if the last item has same key, update it (items are sorted by `donateTo`)
    var _last = _.last(memo);
    if(_last && _last.donateTo === item.donateTo){
        _last.amount += item.amount;
        _last.count++;
    // otherwise create it
    } else {
        memo.push( _.extend( _.omit(item, 'date'), {'count':1} ) );
    }
    return memo
}, []), 'amount');
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore golf...

```
var h = {}, c={};
var result = _.max(donations, function(o){ var i = o.donateTo;
    delete o.date; c[i] = ++c[i]||1; o.count=c[i];
    return o.amount = h[i] = (h[i]||0)+o.amount
});
```